# Iterator that excludes the last element

Tags: python, list, iterator

What is a pythonic way to implement an iterator that excludes the last element, without knowing it's length?

An example:

```
>>> list(one_behind(iter(range(10)))
... [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

>>> iter_ = one_behind(iter((3, 2, 1)))
>>> next(iter_)
... 3
>>> next(iter_)
... 2
>>> next(iter_)
... StopIteration
```

A simple approach would be to use a loop and store the previous value, but I'd like something a bit shorter.

Reference implementation using a loop:

```
def one_behind(iter_):
    prev = None
    for i, x in enumerate(iter_):
        if i > 0:
            yield prev
        prev = x
```

Comment: what do you mean by lag behind by one? Iterate to the end minus the last element?

Comment: do you always know the object being passed in?

Comment: Yes, just the iterator, I'm looking for a `one_behind` implementation.

Comment: Iterators can be infinite, what should happen then?

Comment: Continue forever. I've provided a reference implementation.

Comment: It works with my examples, do you know of a counter-example?

Comment: Why was behzad.nouri's solution voted down to -2 and then deleted? It's the only solution coming to mind.

Comment: why not use `iter_[:-1]`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work on iterators, e.g. `iter(range(10))[:-1]
`.

Comment: `range(10)[:-1]`? Does this fit?

Comment: Using a list takes additional memory, thats why i'm going for an iterator solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
import itertools

def behind(it):
    # it = iter(it)  # to handle non-iterator iterable.
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(it)
    next(i1)
    return (next(i2) for x in i1)
```

usage:

```
>>> list(behind(iter(range(3))))
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Marginally simpler than the reference function:

```
def lag(iter):
    previous_item = next(iter)
    for item in iter:
        yield previous_item
        previous_item = item
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
def one_behind(iter):
    q = collections.deque()
    q.append(next(iter))
    while True:
        q.append(next(iter))
        yield q.popleft()
```

#### Runtime:

```
>>> iterator = iter(range(4))
>>> list(one_behind(iterator))
[0, 1, 2]
```